# Is every even square a value of $\varphi(n)$?

Tags: number-theory, totient-function

An exercise asked to give an infinite set of values so that $\varphi(n)$ is a square. One simple answer was to take $n=2^{2k+1}.$ Here $\varphi(n)$ is Euler's totient function.

My question is whether every even square is the value of $\varphi(n)$ for some $n.$ [I found it so for several small even squres.]

Comment: From the [OEIS list A002202](https://oeis.org/A002202) it looks like $484=22^2$ is not a value for $\varphi(n)$.  Neither is $1156=34^2$.

Comment: Yes, @lulu I just found 484 and so now I'm wondering which even squares, guess I can just scan your OEIS list. Thanks.

Comment: I have an infinite family of counterexamples, writing that up now.

Comment: See also: [Prove that there are infinitely many even nontotients](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2883927).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are infinitely many counterexamples.

We'll build  counterexamples of the form $A_p=(2p)^2$ where $p$ is an odd prime.  We note that the factors of $A_p$ are $\{1,2,4,p,p^2,2p,2p^2,4p,4p^2\}$.

Suppose that $A_p=\varphi(n)$ for some $n$.  Clearly $n$ can't be a power of $2$ so there must be some odd prime $q$ dividing $n$. It is easy to eliminate the cases in which the only odd primes dividing $n$ are $3,5$ so assume that $q>5$. In that case $q-1\,|\,\varphi(n)$ so $q-1$ must be a divisor of $A_p$.  To get a counterexample we just need $p$ such that no odd prime $q$ is one greater than any divisor of $A_p$.  Of course $p+1,p^2+1$ are even.  To ensure that $2p+1,2p^2+1$ are composite take $p\equiv 1 \pmod 3$.  To ensure that $4p+1,4p^2+1$ are composite take $p\equiv 1 \pmod 5$.  To ensure all of the above, take $p\equiv 1 \pmod {15}$. By Dirichlet, there are infinitely many such primes and we are done.

Comment: lulu-- Just wanted to say how nice this example is, and clearly explained also.

Comment: Thanks! $ \,\,$